# How to terminate a function when user wants?

Tags: swift

I have a function that gets data from web. But while this function perform, it takes a while. Therefore I've added a stop button. But how can I terminate a function when user tap the stop button?

Function to terminate:

```
func getData(param: String) -> String{

        //param can be one of these = row, name, channel, rating, share
        var xPath: String = ""
        if param == "row" {
            xPath = "/html/body/table[4]/tr[4]/td[@class='sayfa_ic']/table/tr[2]/td/table//tr/td[1]/b"
        } else if param == "name" {
            xPath = "/html/body/table[4]/tr[4]/td[@class='sayfa_ic']/table/tr[2]/td/table//tr/td[2]"
        } else if param == "channel" {
            xPath = "/html/body/table[4]/tr[4]/td[@class='sayfa_ic']/table/tr[2]/td/table//tr/td[3]"
        } else if param == "rating" {
            xPath = "/html/body/table[4]/tr[4]/td[@class='sayfa_ic']/table/tr[2]/td/table//tr/td[4]"
        } else if param == "share" {
            xPath = "/html/body/table[4]/tr[4]/td[@class='sayfa_ic']/table/tr[2]/td/table//tr/td[6]"
        } else {
            return ""
        }
        let html = Ji(htmlURL: NSURL(string: URL!)!)//takes a while
        let titleNode = html!.xPath(xPath)!
        return String(titleNode)
    }
```

Comment: You're gonna have to give us more than that. Can you post the function that you're referencing?

Comment: I don't understand why you would need more info. He has that function and wants to stop it at any point. Just because there isn't much code doesn't mean that it's a bad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using NSURLSessionTask, call `task.cancel()`.

Documentation:

```
/* -cancel returns immediately, but marks a task as being canceled.
 * The task will signal -URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: with an
 * error value of { NSURLErrorDomain, NSURLErrorCancelled }.  In some 
 * cases, the task may signal other work before it acknowledges the 
 * cancelation.  -cancel may be sent to a task that has been suspended.
 */
```

This will be difficult using a Synchronous API; You need an asynchronous API, and calling cancel will just create an error, as could happen for any number of reasons anyway and which you should be handling correctly.